# How was the true nature of Sibyls kept a secret for so long?

Tags: the-snow-queen

In Joan D. Vinge's *Snow Queen* series, the true nature of the Sibyls has been kept a secret from the people of Tiamat, including Arienrhod, the Snow Queen.  I find this immensely unbelievable. Am I missing something?  A few points:

1. Arienrhod's lovers and advisors ("Starbucks") are typically offworlders.  They would tell her.
2. There is a huge criminal underground of offworlders in Carbuncle.  They would let something slip, either accidentally or for money.  Keep in mind the power of Arienrhod's espionage apparatus.  More importantly, keep in mind that **these are criminals, many of whom work directly with her and are at odds with the Hegemony.**  Even if the Hegemony/Survey suppression of the truth was unimaginably brutal and thorough, I would still expect the Queen to find out/be told hundreds or thousands of time over her long reign.
3. I am in the middle of the sequel *Tangled Up in Blue*, which deals with some of the offworld "Blues", or Hegemonic policemen. There are large numbers of these underpaid working-class people who I presume all know the secret.  Many drink heavily out in the city and visit prostitutes; most seem lonely. I find it implausible that even a few of them could keep the secret from Arienrhod's networks for a few months, much less the whole police force for 100 years.

Am I missing something/making a false assumption or is this an enormous plothole?  I understand the smear campaign conducted by the Hegemony to mislead the Tiamatans about the nature of the Sibyls.  If one drunk Blue started talking he would probably be ignored because of that misinformation.  But it's a whole giant force of Blues and an enormous criminal/smuggling underground.  Arienrhod and her underlings would have to be incredibly dense to not eventually figure it out.

If possible, please avoid spoilers for the 3 sequels; I am only part-way through *Tangled* and haven't read the other two.

Comment: Are you sure that the Queen didn't know?  It's been a long time, but from what I can remember it wouldn't exactly be in her interests to reveal the truth.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I listened to the book, and am unable to find a pdf online, so I cannot come up with a quote.  However, the truth about the Sibyls (they are terminals connected to an AI consciousness designed to bootstrap a civilization to the technological heights required for exploring the galaxy) would have been of enormous importance to the queen. Her goal was to "change the change" and make Tiamat technologically independent. She, however, like the rest of the Winters, viewed the Sibyls as superstitious Summers (which was true in a sense). I am certain that she did not know.

Comment: A quote from *Tangled*:
"the...Winters of Carbuncle convinced that sibyls were lunatics...Even Arienrhod did not suspect the truth--and she could never be permitted to learn it."

Comment: Right you are, my mistake.  I don't think the Starbucks would be likely to tell the Queen, because it would undermine their own position.  But your points about the criminal underground and the Blues seem reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'd be curious to hear more about your reasoning about the Starbucks not telling her.  Their job description is something along the lines of "inform and advise the Queen about the nature of the Hegemony to prevent her from being taken advantage of."  This seems to fall pretty squarely in that category.  Also, even if one or two Starbucks decided not to tell her, there was a long line of them, many of whom were madly, desperately in love with her! (And desperate to keep their positions because of the Water of Life.)

Comment: It should also be noted that most Starbucks were violent, desperate men.  Their job/life-spans were also not very long (measured by the length of time before Arienrhod gets bored).  Even if it was against their long-term interest to tell her the truth, most probably wouldn't realize it, wouldn't care, or would know that they likely wouldn't live long enough for it to matter anyway.

Comment: My reasoning is that if the Queen knew about the Sibyls, she wouldn't need the Starbucks any more.  So even in the short term, it would be against their interests, and I don't think they'd care whether it was in their job description or not. :-)